# sql dynamic variables are not executing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

After trying to find out the problem myself doing some debugging

I have found that @cols and @cols2 variables are not bringing a result , I have PRINT

```
PRINT('INSERT INTO [' + @Destination_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + '] (' + @cols2 + ']' + ') SELECT [' + @cols2 + ']' + ' FROM [' + @Source_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + ']');
```

And the statement will not show the output all I get is

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
I am here2

c365online_script1
I am here3
tCompany

This is the section of the code which I think is the problem

```
   Print 'I am here2'
                        SET IDENTITY_INSERT c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany ON
                        declare @cols2 varchar(max)
                        PRINT @cols2
                        select @cols2 = (Select Stuff((Select '],[' + C.COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Columns From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = @tablename)
                        PRINT('INSERT INTO [' + @Destination_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + '] (' + @cols2 + ']' + ') SELECT [' + @cols2 + ']' + ' FROM [' + @Source_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + ']');
                        PRINT @Destination_Database_Name
                         Print 'I am here3'
                         Print @tablename
                    END
```

I can post full code on request

Comment: quick thought: any chance @cols2 is null?

Comment: print out @cols2, see what it looks like.  Also, I think you need SET cols2 =..., not SELECT (Like John Turner said below while I was slowly typing!)

Comment: @cols2 wont print at all thats the issue , maybe I didnt explain it well

Comment: you've got a mismatched ']' in your code...  `'] (' + @cols2 + ']' + ') SELECT ['` should be `'] ([' + @cols2 + ']) SELECT ['`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SET @cols2 = (Select....)
```

instead of

```
SELECT @cols2 = (Select....)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a NULL concatenation problem.  Try initializing your variables as empty strings, like this, and see what you learn about the results of your query:

```
    declare @tablename varchar(128) = '', 
            @Destination_Database_Name varchar(128) = '', 
            @Source_Database_Name varchar(128) = '';
```